# What type of connector is on this NAS-like storage device?

Tags: connector, networking, network-interface

I have a NAS kind of box, which I got it from my old office when they were moving out, at first I thought this was a simple Ethernet cable, but it is not. Any idea what this connection is?

[image]
Another one:
[image]

Comment: Which connector are you asking about?

Comment: The D-shaped ones remind me of a PCI-Express external expansion connector. Seems like it might have the correct number of pins too (18).

Comment: @DwayneReid the ethernet looking type ones.. the below ones are SAS.. which I already know

Comment: 4-pin conductor?

Comment: Unless you have a good reason for removing the images, such as them containing sensitive material, it would be best for future visitors and potential answerers for them to remain.

Comment: @Mokubai wanted to upload better angle pictures.. but since u added it back then its ok..

Answer (score 1):

[image: conectors]

you can match it from this template:

I see clearly a RJ12 adn RJ45 Female Connectors.

Comment: Probably RJ12's but need to confirm on that..

Comment: in CH2 you have RJ12 and RJ 45. I cant watch clear the 3rd one but seems you arent asking about it.

Comment: no it is not two ports.. only one port but TWO of them

Answer (score 0):

They look like RJ-11 jacks, used for serial console connections. They're smaller than DB-9's, and much more convenient for patch panels with multiple connections in a rack. They are narrower and have fewer connections than the RJ-45's used for X-Base-T ethernets.

Comment: but arent those the ones used for telephone lines? any pictures to the specific ones? all i am getting is the traditional phone cable

Comment: Yes, it's the same connector as used for most phone lines. That's why they were used: cheap and readily available. What the vendor and model of your "NAS kind of box?" They'll probably have the documentation.

Comment: but cant really think why they will be used here.. cause this is a storage box..

Comment: Might you ever need a console connection to the storage box, say to configure new or replacement disks?

Comment: nah.. then there should only be one... but this seems to be having redundant setup and also as this is 8 bays, there are 2 channels with the same connection, doesn't make sense.

Comment: It is also very possible that it was capable of running an IP phone service like asterisk through those ports, we used to use them. But as mentioned, the manual will probably shed some more light.